# How I can swap two values in same column with dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, swap, dynamic-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I have many tables, each table contains **ID** field and **TheOrder** field.

I want to create a **stored procedure** which can swap values of two records in **TheOrder** field.

I am getting the **IDs** of these records by **ASP.NET** code and pass them to the stored procedure.

But because I want to execute this **stored procedure** on many tables, I have to use dynamic SQL and pass table name from **ASP.NET** code.

My **stored procedure** code is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SwapOrders]
    @TblName nvarchar(20)
    , @ID1 int
    , @ID2 int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID1Str nvarchar(5)
    SET @ID1Str = CAST(@ID1 AS nvarchar)
    DECLARE @ID2Str nvarchar(5)
    SET @ID2Str = CAST(@ID2 AS nvarchar)
    DECLARE @Order1 nvarchar(5)
    DECLARE @Order2 nvarchar(5)
    DECLARE @Cmd nvarchar(100)
    /* Get orders */
    SET @Cmd = 'SELECT @Order1 = [TheOrder] FROM ' + @TblName + ' WHERE ID = ' + @ID1Str
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Cmd, "@Order1 nvarchar(5) OUTPUT", @Order1 = [TheOrder]
    SET @Cmd = 'SELECT @Order2 = [TheOrder] FROM ' + @TblName + ' WHERE ID = ' + @ID2Str
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Cmd, "@Order2 nvarchar(5) OUTPUT", @Order2 = [TheOrder]
    /* Update orders */
    SET @Cmd = 'UPDATE ' + @TblName + ' SET TheOrder = @Order2 WHERE ID = ' + @ID1Str
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Cmd, "@Order2 nvarchar(5)", @Order2
    SET @Cmd = 'UPDATE ' + @TblName + ' SET TheOrder = @Order1 WHERE ID = ' + @ID2Str
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Cmd, "@Order1 nvarchar(5)", @Order1
END
GO
```

When I tested this code, two values of **TheOrder** field become **NULL**.

What is the problem?

Thanks very much for any help, and I am sorry for long question.

Comment: @Mahmoud This is across 2 records...

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi, Well, I noticed the two conditions in the `SET` and the `UPDATE` clauses are the same within the same table, so I thought he could do it in one `UPDATE` clause directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c763/2/1)

The code is below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SwapOrders]
  @TblName nvarchar(20),
  @ID1 int,
  @ID2 int
AS
set nocount on
DECLARE @Cmd nvarchar(max) =
 'set nocount on;
  update t
  set TheOrder = u.TheOrder
  from ' + quotename(@tblname) + 't
  join ' + quotename(@tblname) + 'u on
  u.id=case when t.id=@id1 then @id2 else @id1 end
  where t.id in (@id1,@id2);';
exec sp_executesql @cmd, N'@id1 int,@id2 int', @id1, @id2;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks very much @RichardTheKiwi, you rescued me from be mad, you are an excellent man.